# Get statistics for a list of numbers using GPU

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, gpu, gpgpu

I have several lists of numbers on a file . For example,

```
.333, .324, .123 , .543, .00054
.2243, .333, .53343 , .4434
```

Now, I want to get the number of times each number occurs using the GPU. I believe this will be faster to do on the GPU than the CPU because each thread can process one list. What data structure should I use on the GPU to easily get the above counts. For example , for the above, the answer will look as follows:

```
.333 = 2 times in entire file
.324 = 1 time
```

etc..

I looking for a general solution. Not one that works only on devices with specific compute capability

Just writing kernel suggested by Pavan to see if I have implemented it efficiently:

```
int uniqueEle = newend.valiter – d_A;

int* count;
cudaMalloc((void**)&count, uniqueEle * sizeof(int)); // stores the count of each unique element
int TPB = 256;
int blocks = uniqueEle + TPB -1 / TPB;
//Cast d_I to raw pointer called d_rawI
launch<<<blocks,TPB>>>(d_rawI,count,uniqueEle);

__global__ void launch(int *i, int* count, int n){
    int id = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    __shared__ int indexes[256];
    if(id < n ){
        indexes[threadIdx.x] = i[id];
        //as occurs between two blocks
        if(id % 255 == 0){
            count[indexes] = i[id+1] - i[id];
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if(id < ele - 1){
        if(threadIdx.x < 255)
            count[id] = indexes[threadIdx.x+1] – indexes[threadIdx.x];

    }
}
```

Question: how to modify this kernel so that it handles arrays of arbitrary size. I.e , handle the condition when the total number of threads < number of elements

Comment: About how long are your lists of numbers? are they all 32-bit floats?

Comment: @programmer: what exactly is it that you think that kernel code does (leaving aside the fact it won't compile)?

Comment: @talonmies: it computes the difference between the values of two consecutive array indexes

Comment: @Programmer: there are some pretty nonsensical things in that "code". Have a look at my answer for something that might be what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Programmer, it may be nice to post the edited code I provided over chat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I would do the code in matlab

```
A = [333, .324, .123 , .543, .00054 .2243, .333, .53343 , .4434];
[values, locations] = unique(A);   % Find unique values and their locations
counts = diff([0, locations]);     % Find the count based on their locations
```

There is no easy way to do this in plain cuda, but you can use existing libraries to do this.

1) [**Thrust**](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/)

It is also being shipped with CUDA toolkit from CUDA 4.0.

The matlab code can be roughly translated into thrust by using the following functions. I am not too proficient with thrust, but I am just trying to give you an idea on what routines to look at.

```
float _A[] = {.333, .324, .123 , .543, .00054 .2243, .333, .53343 , .4434};
int _I[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
float *A, *I; 
// Allocate memory on device and cudaMempCpy values from _A to A and _I to I
int num = 9;
// Values vector
thrust::device_vector<float>d_A(A, A+num);
// Need to sort to get same values together    
thrust::stable_sort(d_A, d_A+num);
// Vector containing 0 to num-1
thrust::device_vector<int>d_I(I, I+num);
// Find unique values and elements
thrust::device_vector<float>d_Values(num), d_Locations(num), d_counts(num);
// Find unique elements
thrust::device_vector<float>::iterator valiter;
thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator idxiter;
thrust::pair<valiter, idxiter> new_end;
new_end = thrust::unique_by_key(d_A, d_A+num, d_I, d_Values, d_Locations);
```

You now have the locations of the first instance of each unique value. You can now launch a kernel to find the differences between adjacent elements from 0 to new_end in d_Locations. Subtract the final value from num to get the count for final location.

**EDIT** (Adding code that was provided over chat)

Here is how the difference code needs to be done

```
#define MAX_BLOCKS 65535
#define roundup(A, B) = (((A) + (B) - 1) / (B))

int uniqueEle = newend.valiter – d_A;
int* count;
cudaMalloc((void**)&count, uniqueEle * sizeof(int));

int TPB = 256;
int num_blocks = roundup(uniqueEle, TPB);
int blocks_y = roundup(num_blocks, MAX_BLOCKS);
int blocks_x = roundup(num_blocks, blocks_y);
dim3 blocks(blocks_x, blocks_y);

kernel<<<blocks,TPB>>>(d_rawI, count, uniqueEle);

__global__ void kernel(float *i, int* count, int n)
{
int tx = threadIdx.x;
int bid = blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x;
int id = blockDim.x * bid + tx;
__shared__ int indexes[256];

if (id < n) indexes[tx] = i[id];
__syncthreads();

if (id < n - 1) {
if (tx < 255) count[id] = indexes[tx + 1] - indexes[tx];
else count[id] = i[id + 1] - indexes[tx];
}

if (id == n - 1) count[id] = n - indexes[tx];
return;
}
```

2) [**ArrayFire**](http://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire_cuda/)

This is an easy to use, *free* array based library.

You can do the following in ArrayFire.

```
using namespace af;
float h_A[] = {.333, .324, .123 , .543, .00054 .2243, .333, .53343 , .4434};
int num = 9;
// Transfer data to device
array A(9, 1, h_A);
array values, locations, original;
// Find the unique values and locations
setunique(values, locations, original, A);
// Locations are 0 based, add 1.
// Add *num* at the end to find count of last value. 
array counts = diff1(join(locations + 1, num));
```

*Disclosure: I work for [AccelerEyes](http://www.accelereyes.com/), that develops this software.*

Comment: But in this case you are assuming that you know all the unique values. What if you dont know all the unique values?

Comment: +Programmer, The algorithm finds the unique values in the process of finding your final results. It does not expect unique valuse to begin with.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just curious : Does any of the above thrust functions rely on atomic operators?

Comment: Programmer, We have written functions which are functionally equivalent to those used by thrust. I dont think any of them require atomic operations.

Comment: No, I was referring to the original thrust functions like unique_key. Does this use atomic operators

Comment: Programmer, I meant since we dont use atomic operations for similar functions, ideally  they shouldnt either. These algorithms can be done effeciently without using atomic operations. I have not looked into their source code to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Two last question before I accept your answer. I will edit my original question and write the pseudo code for the kernel that you suggested for thrust . Can you please let me know if my implementation is fast. Secondly, isn't unique_by_key a form of stream compaction

Comment: Programmer, you will need to subtract the final value (id[n]) from n to get the count of last location. This algorithm is going to be limited by bandwidth. So you can avoid reading things twice if you can read chunks of data into shared memory and then re-use them for subtraction. unique_by_key uses stream compaction internally. It uses prefix scan which does not require atomic operations.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7393/discussion-between-pavan-and-programmer)

Comment: I have edited the code to use the shared memory version . Please let me know if that looks fast. Lastly, I dont know how to modify the above kernel such that it can handle arrays of arbitrary size ie cases when number of elements is greater than max num of threads that can be launced.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the latest addenum to this question - the diff kernel which would complete the [thrust](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/) method [proposed by Pavan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9147995/681865) could look something like this:

```
template<int blcksz>
__global__ void diffkernel(const int *i, int* count, const int n) { 
    int id = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x; 
    int strd = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    int nmax = blcksz * ((n/blcksz) + ((n%blcksz>0) ? 1 : 0));

    __shared__ int indices[blcksz+1]; 

    for(; id<nmax; id+=strd) {
        // Data load
        indices[threadIdx.x] = (id < n) ? i[id] : n; 
        if (threadIdx.x == (blcksz-1)) 
            indices[blcksz] = ((id+1) < n) ? i[id+1] : n; 

        __syncthreads(); 

        // Differencing calculation
        int diff = indices[threadIdx.x+1] - indices[threadIdx.x];

        // Store
        if (id < n) count[id] = diff;

        __syncthreads(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

here is a solution:

```
__global__ void counter(float* a, int* b, int N)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;

    if(idx < N)
    {
        float my = a[idx];
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if(my == a[i])
                count++;
        }

        b[idx]=count;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int threads = 9;
    int blocks = 1;
    int N = blocks*threads;
    float* h_a;
    int* h_b;
    float* d_a;
    int* d_b;

    h_a = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    h_b = (int*)malloc(N*sizeof(int));

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a,N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_b,N*sizeof(int));

    h_a[0]= .333f; 
    h_a[1]= .324f;
    h_a[2]= .123f;
    h_a[3]= .543f;
    h_a[4]= .00054f;
    h_a[5]= .2243f;
    h_a[6]= .333f;
    h_a[7]= .53343f;
    h_a[8]= .4434f;

    cudaMemcpy(d_a,h_a,N*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    counter<<<blocks,threads>>>(d_a,d_b,N);

    cudaMemcpy(h_b,d_b,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%f = %d times\n",h_a[i],h_b[i]);
    }

    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_b);
    free(h_a);
    free(h_b);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are printing .333f twice which is wrong. Secondly, you are just using 1 block. Moreover, how do you determine the number of unique elements??? Did you just begin CUDA programming?

Comment: According to your question: "I want to get the number of times each number occurs using the GPU". And i will highlight the sentence "each number". This is exactly what you asked for. The 1 block is only due to your example where you have 9 elements in total.

Comment: Do you think your solution is more efficient than Pavan's?

Comment: Brano, You have a for loop of size N for each thread?! Do you even realize how ridiculous that is for CUDA programming ?

Comment: Maybe it is a ridiculous solution but at least i was the only one giving him a pure CUDA implementation. My solution is still modifiable and does not rely on a existing library where you have no control over. People also need to realize that both thrust and ArrayFire are wrappers that wrapp-up lots of API calls which the programmer does not see and could cause confusion such as multiple kernel calls and even worse, alloc and free that will have a huge performance impact where you could have reused the memory.

Comment: And last thig to point out is that the author stated the following: "I have several lists of numbers on a file". This means that he needs to load the data from disk. Now if he is sitting on a RAID solution with SSD he would be lucky to peak 5GB/s. He would be better of solving the problem by counting everything while streaming from disk. Do you even realize how ridiculous that is for CUDA programming ? @Pavan: Yes i do, do you?

Comment: @brano, say he has an array of 10,000 elements, the kernel you showed would just time out on many machines. Considering that the kernel does not time out, you are not utilizing any benefits of CUDA, not even the most basic things such as shared memory that can greatly reduce the read overhead. You just put a serial code inside a CUDA kernel and expect it to be called a CUDA program ?

Comment: This is exactly what I am talking about. While you could find 100 optimizations in mine code I am afraid that you can't analyze your code the same way. You have no idea how thrust and ArrayFire is running it's code by just looking at your post. You also have no idea if your code uses shared memory.

Comment: @brano: What does RAID solution mean?

Comment: RAID=Redundant array of individual discs.