# Calculating differences between consecutive indices fast

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

Given that I have the array

```
Let Sum be 16
dintptr = { 0 , 2, 8,11,13,15}
```

I want to compute the difference between consecutive indices using the GPU. So the final array should be as follows:

```
count = { 2, 6,3,2,2,1}
```

Below is my kernel:

```
//for this function n is 6

__global__ void kernel(int *dintptr, int * count, int n){

   int id = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
   __shared__ int indexes[256];
   int need = (n % 256 ==0)?0:1;
   int allow = 256 * ( n/256 + need);
   while(id < allow){
     if(id < n ){
       indexes[threadIdx.x] = dintptr[id];

     }
     __syncthreads();
     if(id < n - 1 ){
       if(threadIdx.x % 255 == 0 ){
            count[id] = indexes[threadIdx.x + 1] - indexes[threadIdx.x];
       }else{
            count[id] = dintptr[id+1] - dintptr[id];
       }


    }//end if id<n-1
      __syncthreads();
     id+=(gridDim.x * blockDim.x);
    }//end while
}//end kernel
// For last element explicitly set count[n-1] = SUm - dintptr[n-1]
```

2 questions:

1. Is this kernel fast. Can you suggest a faster implementation?
2. Does this kernel handle arrays of arbitrary size ( I think it does)

Comment: Have you tested/timed/profiled your code ? What did you learn ?

Comment: @programmer: I think you are missing a third question "is the code correct", to which the answer is no, because there is a potential deadlock as written.

Comment: It also assumes a block size of 256 (I think).

Comment: @talonmies: Great suggestion! I have removed part of the deadlock by shifting the second __syncthreads outside the if(id < n-1) condition. However, there can still be deadlock if some threads in a thread block have id's < n while others do not. Any idea how to avoid this while maintaining the condition that the code should handle array of any size

Comment: @programmer: yes, I already posted it on [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9173678/681865)

Comment: @talonmies: I will go through that one. But I will be highly obliged if you could suggest me how I should modify the above code to remove the deadlock :)

Comment: @talonmies: The reason is that for me, its easier to learn by seeing how my code can be improved rather than seeing an already improved code

Comment: @talonmies: NOW, my code should not have deadlocks. I just modified it

Comment: Programmer @talonmies and myself have provided you the relavent code in your other question. There really is no need for a different question.

Comment: @Pavan: I just wanted to let people have a look at my implementation to clarify my concept. I am sorry it that is not allowed. Anyways, I have accepted your answer. Can you please let me know if my above code still has deadlocks?

Comment: Fair enough. Here is the problem. You misplaced a brace. The second from last } should be after id += ...

Comment: @pAVAN: i dont think so. I have re edited my code so that the indentation is better. Please have a look again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll bite.

```
__global__ void kernel(int *dintptr, int * count, int n)
{
    for (int id = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x; 
         id < n-1; 
         id += gridDim.x * blockDim.x)
        count[id] = dintptr[id+1] - dintptr[i];
}
```

(Since you said you "explicitly" set the value of the last element, and you didn't in your kernel, I didn't bother to set it here either.)

I don't see a lot of advantage to using shared memory in this kernel as you do: the L1 cache on Fermi should give you nearly the same advantage since your locality is high and reuse is low.

Both your kernel and mine appear to handle arbitrary-sized arrays.  Yours however appears to assume blockDim.x == 256.

Comment: Mark, you are a braver man that I! I think the questioner was planning on running this on older hardware, so a shared memory version might have an advantage for pre-Fermi version, but I agree, on Fermi L1 cache is surprisingly efficient for differencing and similar.

Comment: @harrism: My first solution was the same as yours. I am just curious how to code the shared memory one :)

Comment: @harrism: Why will someone give me -1 for such an interesting question ?

Comment: Not sure.  Maybe because you are asking questions that only you can/should answer.  Is it fast?  Well, compared to what?  The real question is "is it fast enough?"  If it's not a bottleneck in your app , then it's fast enough.

Comment: @harrism : can you pls check if my code still has deadlocks. I just modified it

Comment: @harrism, may be he would not have had to write the difference kernel if there adjacent_difference from thrust was more extensible. Just saying :p

Comment: Programmer: have you run the code? Talonmies was the one who found your deadlock problem.@Pavan: Since you are a thrust user, if you have feature requests please file an issue on the Thrust google code site.